# Mystery 1px border in WebKit

Tags: css, webkit

I have a mystery 1px bottom border showing up in Safari and Chrome (I guess a WebKit thing). Firefox displays it fine.

The button below should sit flush with the *tealy* bar beneath. There should not be that 1px line separating them.

[image: WebKit Example]

I've played around with `height`, `border`, `position`, `padding` and `margin` but haven't been able to figure this one out.

Changing `bottom: 0` to `bottom: -5px` in Web Inspector still produces the line.

There are quite a lot of styles going into it, so I'll try and amalgamate the cascade.

```
#tell-a-friend {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  display:block;
  height:33px;
  margin-right:0;
  position:absolute;
  float:right;
  font-size:1.2em;
  margin-right:0.8em; 
  background-position:right 0;
  bottom:0;
  height:35px !important;
  left:682px;
  width:82px;
}
```

Then again, I may be better off [linking to the site](https://www.bustersdirect.com.au/).

The CSS is minified, so use Web Inspector to view the CSS.

I've tried everything I can think of right now, so I'm going to see if you guys can help me :)

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post more code - we do not have access to the HTML. If available, please post a link to the live version. I will then have a butchers at it.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy I did do that... see link above :)

Comment: Sorry - I misread it... its getting late...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: it's your `<div id="header">`'s absolute height. Try making it one pixel shorter.

[image]

<s>It's not a black outline, it's the gray background... the background image has a 1px transparent row on the bottom, and the gray background shows through.</s>

Comment: I thought of that, but using Web Inspector I set `height: 10px` and it was still happening. Shouldn't that work if it did have 1px transparent at bottom of image (i.e. it should be cut off by the containing element)?

Comment: @no Thanks very much :) And you are right! I thought `bottom: 0` would mean that would be unlikely, but there must be another `position: relative` somewhere.